# Nodejs with reverser proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm currently using NodeJs over Nginx for hosting a website, since I've already realized the port conflict of Nginx, I already change the configure file and I can access localhost now.
But the problem is the website is no longer the same as the one hosted on port 3000(which I set the NodeJs source to listen)
It is really struggling and I really do wish someone can get me a solution.

The configure code is list below

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
 root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name _;
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
```

Comment: Your NodeJS is listening to port 3000 and yet you are proxy-passing to localhost:8080? Can you post your entire server block in the nginx config file?

Comment: Nah my bad, these was the source code I found on another blog.

Comment: https://imgur.com/eN1ZFXg

Comment: https://imgur.com/MNsQIHS

Comment: The link of screenshot is under comment, I'm not sure about is this enough, but seems like the CSS file is not loaded.

Comment: Could you post your entire server block here? Also, could you post how you are trying to load your CSS files? What is the location under which you are doing proxy-pass?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I've changed the server block now, I haven't try loading my css after the proxy, the proxy file is under /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.

Comment: Do you have any other locations inside this server block? Also, could you paste how you are including your CSS file in your HTML? When you use relative links behind a proxy like in this instance, there are possibilities of wrong location mapping.

Comment: The other files are the default configuration which provided by Nginx. I realized that only the main page is partially working, the functional sub page is not working as well, not only the css. I've spend some time go through blogs but I cannot find proper description for my problem.